# Access Error: The specified field <ID> could refer to more than one table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

My query and VBA command that generate this error are extremely simple but I am missing something.

I have a button in a form that creates a report. The reports has the following query as a record source:

```
SELECT Bewerber.*, Recruiter.*, sys_var.*
FROM (Recruiter INNER JOIN Bewerber ON Recruiter.ID = Bewerber.Recruiter)
INNER JOIN sys_var ON Recruiter.Key &"_FRAGEN" = sys_var.Key;
```

All of these tables have an ID.

This is the code for the `Button.Click` event:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptRecruitingvorlage", acViewPreview, , "Bewerber.ID = " & ID
```

What am I missing??

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Check this line:   `FROM (Recruiter INNER JOIN Bewerber ON Recruiter.ID = Bewerber.Recruiter)`

Comment: You mean the "()"? VBA wants them there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Bewerber.ID`?

Comment: the field with the ID of the recruiter in the Bewerber table is named "Recruiter". The Recruiter.ID and Bewerber.ID are totally different and indicate records sets of the two tables. They are not associated.
This line that you are asking about is the same as `Recruiter.ID = Bewerber.RecruiterID`